# Checking the contents of a file using a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hosts

I want to create a batch file that checks if the computer's HOSTS file has a line with the string "youtube.com" and if there is any that will perform an action (open chrome browser) and I do not succeed. The current code is:

```
if (find "www.youtube.com" C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) (
start chrome.exe
```

)

Would appreciate help!

Comment: `find /i "www.youtube.com" "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" >nul 2>&1 && start "" "chrome.exe"`

Comment: It works on cmd but not on batch file. What can be done?

Comment: I'm wondering if you're using the right approach: when a host is entered in the /etc/hosts file, then no DNS needs to be done in order to find the IP address, there should be some command that verifies that. So instead of parsing that file yourself, you might try to compare DNS lookup command results.

Comment: There is no reason, it wouldn't run in a batch file. Check for typos and the correct encoding ("Ansi") of the batch file.

Comment: If it's not running in a script, try change the properties to run with admin privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with absolute path. Had the same issue and fixed it on this way.
It seems since MS changed Edge to Chromium it's impossible to call native chrome with start chrome.exe